# Is it possible in Orchard to dynamically change HTML in a shape right before rendering?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.10

This is the markup for `Content.ThumbnailSummary.cshtml`, a custom DisplayType I use to render ContentItems as clickable thumbnails with their contents absolutely positioned over them.

```cs
@using Orchard.Utility.Extensions;
@{
    var contentTypeClassName = ((string)Model.ContentItem.ContentType).HtmlClassify();
}
<a class="content-item @contentTypeClassName thumbnail-summary">
    @Display(Model.Header)
    <div class="thumbnail-summary-inner">
        @Display(Model.Content)
    </div>
    @Display(Model.Footer)
</a>
```

The problem is that out of the box most Parts and Fields get rendered as links or paragraphs containing links, and nested `<a>` tags mess up DOM rendering pretty badly in most browsers. A ThumbnailSummary should **never** contain any links.

I could create alternates for every field and part, or I could remove everything by default in placement and only add rules for specific cases as I need them. But that would be pretty tedious and defeats a lot of the benefits of placement, so I was hoping I could somehow strip or replace all `<a>` tags in code only for shapes with this DisplayType.

I've been looking in this direction but I'm not sure if it's viable:

```cs
public class Shapes : IShapeTableProvider
{
    public void Discover(ShapeTableBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Describe("Content")
            .OnDisplaying(displaying =>
            {
                if (displaying.ShapeMetadata.DisplayType == "ThumbnailSummary")
                {             
                    // Do something here???
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost right, instead of a provider add a class that inherits from `Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.ShapeDisplayEvents` or implement `IShapeDisplayEvents` yourself.

I've done this myself to remove certain functionality from admin area that cannot be disabled via feature or permission.

The code should look like this

```
public class MyShapeDisplayEvents : Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.ShapeDisplayEvents
{
  public override void Displayed(Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.ShapeDisplayedContext context)
  {
    if (context.Shape is Orchard.DisplayManagement.Shapes.Shape)
    {
      Orchard.DisplayManagement.Shapes.Shape lShape = (Orchard.DisplayManagement.Shapes.Shape)context.Shape;

      if (lShape.Metadata.Type == "Layout")
      { 
        string lChildContent = context.ChildContent.ToHtmlString();

        // do something with the content like removing tags

        context.ChildContent = new System.Web.HtmlString(lChildContent);
      }

      ...
```